# how to add a second grid under a tab in magento admin?

Tags: magento, tabs, grid, admin

I'm working on a new Magneto module.
For my Admin panel i've made a Grid "A" and i want to add a Grid "B" under one Tab of the Grid "A".
Just like the Upsells Grid under the Products Grid.
I've made many search but i didn't find something interesting.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Grid Called Grid Serializer Block,  you can find a good tutorial here:

http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/understanding-the-grid-serializer-block/

I have followed the same.

Hope this Help !!

Comment: if i want to be able to edit/add lines on the Grid "B" ! how can i do it ? thx